# How to find who put the sharepoint site collection in READ only mode in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have one sharepoint2010 site. Suddenly i saw today that site has been put into READ only mode. How to audit, who has done this. I want to know who put the site into READ only mode(through CA->Site quotas and locks). Is there any way to find? (through powershell command, SPD, Database or through anyother things)

Thanks
Sivakumar. P

Comment: Are you sure the lock has been put manually? there are some scenarios where a command line operation could also lock the site collection (I think about backup / restore operation especially). That said, I think you will raise your chances of getting an answer on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. I am not sure how the site was put into read only. i will raise this in sharepoint.stackexchange.com